# Action Script 3.0 datatype to match C++ iterator? (Code convertion)

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, starling

I am developing a game with Action Script 3.0 using Starling Framework, converting it from C++

C++ Code :

```
for (std::vector<MyObject*>::iterator i = m_listEnemy->begin();i!= m_listEnemy->end();)
{

    (*i)->update(dt);
    if ( (*i)->m_Hp <=0 )
    {
            (*i)->release();
            i = m_listEnemy->erase(i);
            continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

MyObject is the class.

What Action Script 3.0 data type matches the C++ iterator?
Also , how can I convert this C++ code to Action Script 3.0 code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if we are only talking about vector here then its equvelant to an array you can do the following for(int i=0; i<size; i++) arr[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approaches:

```
for each (var value:MyObject in array)
{
   ...
}

for (var index:int in array) /*or (var prop:* in obj)*/
{
   var value:MyObject = array[index]; //or var value = obj[prop]
   ...
}

for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   var value:MyObject = array[index];
   ...
}
```

There are no native iterators in AS3. You can however download [polygonal](http://lab.polygonal.de/)'s game dev libraries if you want mature, advanced data access capabilities. These libraries are sort of like Boost for AS3 :)

Comment: As for removing objects out of an array: Arrays in as3 automatically reposition the elements when one object is removed. So it's best if the loop is done in reverse (for(var i:int = array.length; i > 0; i--)). It prevents the loop to skip an element.

Comment: Correct. It's either that, or you break the loop immediately on finding the relevant element, store the index, and then remove it outside of the if-block. Removing in while iterating in reverse is a little more concise.

Comment: dear nick Wiggill, can you give me some code :( when remove object from list. Thank you very much